# Show a double using text with Windowbuilder and Java?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtextfield

I'm fairly new to Java coding and I am trying to get a number from a double to display into a JSwing textbox.

The code I'm having trouble with:

```
txtCounter = new JTextField();
txtCounter.setText(counter); //Error here Jtextcomponent not available for Double
txtCounter.setEditable(false);
txtCounter.setToolTipText("Shows time that has passed.");
txtCounter.setBounds(10, 69, 100, 20);
frmTimer.getContentPane().add(txtCounter);
txtCounter.setColumns(10);
```

Is their a different statement I could use for this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to pass a String representation of `counter` to `setText()`. Either of the following lines would work:

```
txtCounter.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
```

Or:

```
txtCounter.setText(counter + "");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass a `String` to `setText()` method:

```
txtCounter = new JTextField();
txtCounter.setText(counter + ""); 
txtCounter.setEditable(false);
txtCounter.setToolTipText("Shows time that has passed.");
txtCounter.setBounds(10, 69, 100, 20);
frmTimer.getContentPane().add(txtCounter);
txtCounter.setColumns(10);
```